# Streaming Video in https

Tags: https

I have an https page, and I've been asked to embed streaming video.  Now I understand the normal policy (the files must also be hosted on https) but are there any other gotchas I should be aware of?

What if I stuck an IFRAME on the page, and streamed the content into that frame from a normal http source?  Would I still get the "secure and insecure content on this page" warning?

Thanks
Duncan

Answer (score 4):

Streaming over `https` seems a really bad idea unless you really NEED your video stream to be secure .

I don't know how every browser deals with a mix of `http` and `https` requests, but I believe if a page served over `http` also makes `https` requests, there usually **won't** be an "insecure content" warning.

However if an `https` page makes `http` requests, this usually **will** trigger an "insecure content" warning.

**Edit:** A thought: if you are using a flash video player, where the flash file is served over `https` but the .flv file is served over `http` - I doubt the browser will be 'clever' enough to detect that, and hence you shouldn't get any warnings - that is my guess - YMMV.

Comment: What about embedding in the IFRAME?  Any experience with this?

Comment: I suspect, as you do, that an http iframe embedded in an https page will cause warnings in most browsers

Answer (score 2):

Please note nowadays Google Chrome throws a warning when a video player embedded on HTTPS is serving content from an HTTPS source. Facebook nowadays services it's mp4 content over https.